# Dual SIM standby -- data and calls on different SIMs

Tags: mobile-data, 4g, dual-sim

I wanna ask about *Dual SIM standby 4G* phones, particularly Lenovo P70 if that makes a difference.

If I have two SIMs: **(A)** with a call and SMS tariff, **(B)** with LTE data.

If I browse the internet on (B) and someone calls me on (A), will I be notified of the call? And if so, when I answer the call, will I disconnect from the internet?

Comment: (I'm new on this site; I haven't found a dupe, but if it exists, I apologize.)

Comment: I didn't check the second case but you'll be notified that an SMS has been received and your ordinary incoming calling view would show up for an incoming call.

Answer (score 3):

As far as phone calls are concerned, when you use SIM1 for a phone call, SIM  2 will be unavailable to receive calls or messages. Anybody that tries to call, the call will not go through.

As far as Data connection is concerned, when you use SIM1 for Data, and you get a call on SIM2, data connection is automatically put on hold, and will continue when the call on SIM1 is finished.

Comment: So the phone is still "listening" on the other SIM when one SIM is used for data?

Comment: Doesn't that rather depend on the dual-sim implementation used? AFAIR there are multiple implementations: one works by switching between the cards (as you describe), and another one gives true multi-sim. Not sure, as I never dug into it.

Comment: @Izzy I forgot to mention it in the post, it's only in the title: It's "dual SIM standby"

Comment: @yo' Ah, so that's what it means. OK, tnx :)

Comment: @Izzy Correct.  There are two kinds, Dual SIM Dual Standby, and Dual SIM Dual Active.  In the active mode, when a call is on one SIM, user will get a notification tone, that there is a call on the other SIM.

Comment: Has anybody tested downloading large file and receiving call on other Sim at the same time?